# how to prevent the duplicate names?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

can any body explain how to stop the duplicate names.if any duplicate name give then i need to display appropriate error message  like "name is already exists".so application consists  following class merchant.java,MerchantDao.java ,MerchantImpl.java class.so i need to implement method in MerchantImpl.java class that method containting logic to stop the duplicate merchant names.

```
Merchat.java

public class Merchant
 {
 private String merchant Name;
etc
 } 

 MerchantImpl.java
  public class MerchantImpl
  {
need to define a method to prevent duplicate names;
     }
```

Comment: do you have a list of all Merchants?

Comment: yes i am having the list of merchants in databse.if i given the already exiting mechantName through merchant.jsp page then it will display "merchant name is already exists" please povide logic.

Comment: i need to implement method like(checkduplicate()) in MerchantImpl i.e need to compare input details with data base names if exists then show  the appropriate error message on the on to the browser so provide  logic

Answer (score 2):

You can override hashCode and equals methods of Merchant class

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return name.hashCode();
}

@Override
// This really depends on if you want to compare only objects or names too.
// The following compares names too.
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    final Merchant other = (Merchant) obj;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

And then, store the Merchant objects in a Set collection (for faster lookup). Add appropriate check to see if new Merchant's name already exists in the Set.

```
Set<Merchant> merchants = new HashSet<>()
// Populated the merchants
```

Now the check

```
// if merchant names are unique
merchants.contains(newMerchantObj)
```

P.S : I would only recommend overriding hashcode with Merchant name's hashcode as you have a requirement to maintain unique names for merchants.

Comment: In this case you might as well override `.equals()`

Comment: please provide logic public int checkDuplicate(){}.this method called from mycontroller class.so provide the logic here

Comment: Dont expect people to Just give you implementation for logics in SO. You got more than 5 answers. Just try implementing any one.

Comment: Thanks @fge for pointing out that we should override equals() too. Added it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Save all names in set and when new name is given check if the name already is in the set. Code could look something like this (you may not need a new class):

```
class NameChecker {
    Set<String> names = new HashSet<String>();

    public void addName(String name) {
        if (names.contains(name)) {
            //print message
        } else {
            names.add(name);
            // do what you have to with new names.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my application containg merchat.java,MerchantDao.java,MerchantImpl.java class so i need to call the checkDuplicates() of Merchant Impl class from mucontroller class(spring-mvc) so prvide the code.i need to compare the form properties(merchantName) with merchantTable in the database

Comment: I would still keep the set in memory for performance reasons and just fill it up when application starts from names already added in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Store names in set. Unfortunately you have not provided code that shows how do you get new names but the following code sample should help you:

// definition
Set names = new HashSet();

// other place in code where you get new name:
if (names.contains(name)) {
    // print error message
}
names.add(name); // add new name.

Answer (score 0):

search the input name in database if it exist then error else insert in database.

```
if(name exist in database)
error
else 
add name in database.
```

the actual code depends on the data structure you use for maintaining the database.

```
if(name_list.contains(name))
error
else 
name_list.add(name);
```